# In Perforce, how to search by content of a file in its revision graph

Tags: grep, perforce

In perforce, is it possible to search for a string in all its revisions and sources. It should be able to search in its entire "Revision graph" from where file could have been derived. I was able to find "p4 grep -a" which can search in revisions of a particular file in a branch. But I want to search in its sources also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only care about strings that are in the current head revision of the file?  If that's an acceptable limitation, `annotate -I` is a pretty easy option:

```
p4 annotate -I file | grep STRING
```

More on `p4 annotate -I` here: https://www.perforce.com/blog/p4-annotate-i-going-deeper

If that doesn't do it for you, you have a lot of scripting ahead of you -- that blog post might help get you started on the general approach (you'd use `p4 filelog` to generate the "graph" and `p4 print` to get the content).

You could also try hacking on the DeepAnnotate tool I wrote before `annotate -I` since that's open source (it's way hackier than `annotate -I` though so I'd still recommend using the built-in version if you can): https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/deepannotate

Comment: p4 annotate -I file | grep STRING will not do. Even, other suggestion also might not be sufficient as I need to recursively go through all the branches from where it could have been integrated and the changes introduced by developer(rather than from other branches). 2nd suggestion cannot recursively go thru all branches right?

Comment: If you're writing your own tool, you're bounded only by your own patience.  Just to be clear, what you describe in your question (`it should be able to search in its entire "Revision graph" from where file could have been derived`) is *exactly* what `annotate -I` does -- it shows you information for all the places that the file was derived from (it just doesn't go in the other direction).

Comment: I appreciate your response. I guess I need to ask question specifically. In my codebase, at certain point of time, a piece of code was removed. I want to search using this piece of code and see when and why it was removed. As this piece of code is not in head revision it could not annotate.

Comment: It would have been simpler for your question to be "is it possible to search for the revision where a string was removed".  :)  If you only have to do this once for one particular line it's going to be faster to do it manually.  Use "p4 annotate -a" on the later file, and if the revision that deleted it was a merge, repeat the process on the merge source.  Continue until you find the origin.

Comment: You *might* be able to hack up DeepAnnotate to do this for deleted lines -- all the data is in there.  It wouldn't be a simple matter of a one-line change though.